# sp_OAMethod http status bad in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 to call `XMLHTTPRequest`.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HTTP_REQUEST
( 
    @URI varchar(200), 
    @response varchar(8000) OUT
)
AS
  DECLARE
     @xhr INT
     ,@result INT
     ,@httpStatus INT
     ,@msg VARCHAR(255)


  EXEC @result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0', @xhr OUT

IF @result <> 0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OACreate on MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0 failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

EXEC @result = sp_OAMethod @xhr, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URI, false
IF @result <>0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod Open failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

EXEC @result = sp_OAMethod @xhr, SEND, NULL, ''
IF @result <>0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod SEND failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

EXEC @result = sp_OAGetProperty @xhr, 'status', @httpStatus OUT
print 'Status: ' +convert(varchar(10),@httpStatus)
IF @result <>0 
    BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod read status failed', 16,1) RETURN 
    END

IF @httpStatus <> 200 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod http status bad', 16,1) RETURN 
END

EXEC @result = sp_OAGetProperty @xhr, 'responseText', @response OUT
IF @result <>0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod read response failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

EXEC @result = sp_OADestroy @xhr
RETURN
GO
```

but when I execute at that time it gives error like..

> status:500
>   sp_OAMethod http status bad..

I have already run

```
enable sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', '1'
GO
reconfigure
GO
```

but it still causes that error.

Can anyone please tell me what should be problem for this?

Comment: By the point at which it reports that *specific* error, it's already been talking to the COM component several times. So we can rule out it being an issue about *using* the `sp_OAMethod` (and similar) procedures. It's saying that it managed to *make* the call to the remote web host but what was returned wasn't what was expected - it was a 500 status - an internal server error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code shown is working exactly as intended - the fault is with whatever system is *responding* to the web request - which at this point, we don't even know if that's code under the control of the OP, and even if so, it's not the code in the question and almost certainly isn't implemented in SQL Server.